# How to write javascript's FileReader() reader.result object to a file at server side using python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django

I'm writing a Jupyterlab extension, in one of its functionality, I'm trying to write file upload functionality which reads the user-selected file and write back to the server. To accomplish the job it uses javascript's FileReader API and then passes the object to python using  JSON.stringify(). However, I'm able to write a file on the server side using a test string but not able to write a file using the file content due to the object compatibility issue.

This code contains both javascript and server-side code.

```
    readFile(data) {
        let file = data.files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = async function() {

        console.log(reader.result);
        console.log('OK');
        var InitialData = await KernelSideDataObjects(`import json\nfile = open('test.txt', 'wb+')\nfile.write('test')`);
        //var InitialData = await KernelSideDataObjects(`import json\nfile = open('test.txt', 'wb+')\nfile.write(${JSON.stringify(reader.result)})`);

        //   console.log(reader.readAsDataURL(file))
        };

        reader.onerror = function() {
          console.log(reader.error);
        };
}
```

How can I translate or decode `reader.result` into a python-compatible manner to write file content in a file?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. You can send a file to the backend using &lt;input type="file"> and that backend can be node (javascript) or python. Why would you be using both?

Comment: I don't see the server side code there, and +1 for the comment from @ControlAltDel

Comment: @ControlAltDel thanks for your reply my backend is a pure python based on ipython kernel

Comment: @AllanElder here is the python code "/var InitialData = await KernelSideDataObjects(`import json\nfile = open('test.txt', 'wb+')\nfile.write(${JSON.stringify(reader.result)})`);" this line send string to ipython kernel where this code execute.